# Copying one sheet to another workbook based on one criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have 2 different workbooks, main and copy.
Row 1 is meant for header/labeling the information it will be providing for both workbooks.

The "main" workbook will be using columns A to N. The copy will be using columns A to M.

The criteria to determine whether the code will be copying is the workbook, "main", column M.

- If the cell contains "X" - it will copy column A to L, and N, to the workbook "copy". After which, it will go on to the next row to determine the same thing.
- If the cell is empty, it will proceed down to the next row to determine the same thing as well.

The code has to be dynamic as new information will be added every 3 months, such as new rows added or the criteria changing from "X" to empty, or empty to "X".

I am a beginner in VBA excel, and have been trying out multiple codes but it doesn't seems to work. Would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: This site works best if you post the code that you currently have written, even though it **isn't** working, so that we can help you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Showing your code so far will help us a lot.

Maybe this helps a little:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim wks_copy As Worksheet
Set wks = Worksheets("main")
Set wks_copy = Worksheets("copy")

j = 2
For i = 2 To wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If wks.Cells(i, 13).Value = "x" Then
        wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 14)).Copy Destination:=wks_copy.Cells(j, 1)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
```

This will copy the entire row. If you don't want to copy column M, I suggest clearing or hiding the column after copying.

If the macro runs again after 3 months, it will overwrite the existing data on Worksheet *copy*. But you should delete the worksheet's values before that, for example by using

```
Worksheets("copy").UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
```

or manually clearing the range.